# Android OutputStreamWriter for HttpURLConnection issue when calling multiple times

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

Synopsis: I have an `AsyncTask` with `doInBackground` method from which I am calling `sendHttpBuffer` to send some strings to the http receiver.

example:

```
String[] tmp = {"TEST TO SEND","<|test123|>"};
sendHttpBuffer(connection,tmp);
... do something in between
String[] tmp2 = {"TEST TO SEND 2","<|test456|>"};
sendHttpBuffer(connection,tmp2);
```

The issue is: when calling `sendHttpBuffer` multiple times, only the first is sent OK.

Am I missing something?

```
private void sendHttpBuffer(HttpURLConnection connection, String[] toSend) {
    if (toSend.length > 0) {
        OutputStreamWriter out= null;
        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            for (String cmd : toSend ) {
                if (!cmd.isEmpty()) {
                    out.write(cmd);
                }
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dont create a new OutputStreamWriter for every call to your function.

Create one and use everywhere.

Comment: You shoul also not close() with every call.

Comment: Indeed, that is the right way. In the meantime I encountered another issue:
write
---
open BufferedReader with InputStreamReader
---
write -> this does not work anymore.

Anyway, I will dig a little more, Thank you!